# Is there a way to make a Vega pie chart "3D"?

Tags: vega

I'm trying to create a pie chart with a slight tilt to give a 3D effect.

I tried adding "depth" and "theta" attributes to the arc mark, but it didn't seem to work.  I'm not really sure what else to try. I tried a few other things too, but everything yields a 2D pie chart in the Vega editor online.

Edit: After David's comment, I've added additional pie charts as underlayers (shift the y position), using a darker shade to give a depth effect.  It's basic, but may meet the look I'm going for:

Here's the Vega Chart:

[image: With layers]

For Reference, this is the chart I'm trying to replicate:
[image]

Comment: Vega doesn't natively support 3D. 3D typically isn't advised for dataviz as it distorts the chart and how it may be interpreted. You could possibly do something using custom SVG paths but it wouldn't be easy. Have a look here to see a perspective bar chart using this technique: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: @DavidBacci - Thanks - nice example!  You got me thinking-- I may be able to just draw the chart with layers to give the effect of depth. I've edited my post and put the chart "showing some depth".  If I have some additional time, I'll look into a more complex solution, but I'll keep in mind the distortion that you mentioned.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.